# ReactJs Map array logic

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem with logic to map one array, basically i have this array structure:
I have a name to render it on my < li> and also a link to use on the react router,
and I have a dropdown object where I will have an array of names and an array of links to do exactly like mine < li>, but only my dropdown < li>

```
        const MenuTags = [
    {
      name: 'home',
      link: '/',
      dropdownItems: {
        names: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
        link: ['/aa', '/b'],
      },
    },
    {
      name: 'about',
      link: '../abovisibleMenuut',
      dropdownItems: {
        names: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
        link: ['/aa', '/b'],
      },
    },
    { name: 'not dropdown', link: '../dashboard' },
    { name: 'not dropdown', link: '../dashboard/about' },
  ];
```

basically i would need to go through these dropdown values ​​to render in my dropdown menu:

```
const MenuItem = ({ tag, visibleMenu }) => {
  const { name, link, dropdownItems } = tag;
  console.log(dropdownItems, 'tag');
  return (
    <NavLi>
      <Link to={link}>{name}</Link>
      {visibleMenu[name] &&
        dropdownItems &&
        dropdownItems.map(item => (
          <ul>
            <li><Link to={item.link}>{item.name}</Link></li>
          </ul>
        ))}
    </NavLi>
  );
};
```

and this is where I have the array and I pass my props to the component above

```
const MenuBar = props => {
  const MenuTags = [
    {
      name: 'home',
      link: '/',
      dropdownItems: {
        names: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
        link: ['/aa', '/b'],
      },
    },
    {
      name: 'about',
      link: '../abovisibleMenuut',
      dropdownItems: {
        names: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
        link: ['/aa', '/b'],
      },
    },
    { name: 'not dropdown', link: '../dashboard' },
    { name: 'not dropdown', link: '../dashboard/about' },
  ];
  const [visibleMenu, setVisibleMenu] = useState(
      MenuTags.reduce((r, e) => ((r[e.name] = false), r), {}),
    ),
    onUpdateVisibility = item => {
      const visibleMenuCopy = { ...visibleMenu };
      Object.keys(visibleMenuCopy).forEach(
        key => (visibleMenuCopy[key] = key === item),
      );
      setVisibleMenu(visibleMenuCopy);
    };
  console.log(visibleMenu);
  return (
    <NavUl isOpen={props.isOpen}>
      {MenuTags.map(item => (
        <MenuItem
          tag={item}
          visibleMenu={visibleMenu}
          onClick={() => onUpdateVisibility(item)}
        />
      ))}
      <li>
        <FontAwesomeIcon
          onClick={() => props.setOpenBox(!props.isOpen)}
          className="searchIcon"
          rotation={90}
          icon={faSearch}
          size="1x"
          fixedWidth
          color="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);"
        />
      </li>
    </NavUl>
  );
};
```

basically my dropdownItems

has this structure:

```
  dropdownItems: {
    names: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
    link: ['/aa', '/b'],
  },
```

and I need to render my li with the name and the link mapping this array
and I don't know how I can map the name and link correctly or if I can improve the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've read this through a few times and I'm struggling to understand what exactly you're asking.  But I see two strange things.

First, you have

```
 dropdownItems: {
    names: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
    link: ['/aa', '/b'],
  }
```

But how can you have 3 names that correspond to 2 links?  This part is not making sense to me, at least the way you've written the question.

Second is in the `dropdownItems.map` statement - you are trying to do this:

```js
dropdownItems.map
```

But `dropdownItems` is an object, not an array.  You can't map over an object.  Probably what's better is to define it like this:

```js
dropdownItems: [
        { name: 'one', link: '/aa'},
        { name: 'two', link: '/b/'} 
      ]

// within the MenuItem:
// now this will work
<ul>
  { dropdownItems.map(item => (
    <li><Link to={item.link}>{item.name}</Link></li>
  )) }
</ul>
```

Comment: Hello thank you very much sorry for the question my english is not good

but the question was really about how to structure and map my array, could you help me how am I going to render this according to this condition?

{visibleMenu [name] &&
        dropdownItems &&

Comment: perhaps you could put this also together in a working example with something like codesandbox so we could play around with it?  your code is very dense (not a bad thing), and hard to follow by just reading without testing it out.

Comment: hi ok i open new question with codesandbox: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60662433/react-js-menu-with-menu-item-drop-down-and-menu-item-active-state

Comment: Is that other post just asking the same question?  That's not necessary...at the end of each question you post you can use the 'edit' button to edit your question.  Might be better to delete that new question and just edit this one...