# React Js / Menu with menu item drop down and menu item active State

Tags: reactjs

hi i have a menu with tag structure < li> < a> and some of these menu items will be dropdown

then I created a state array to store all my menu items and when one is clicked it needs to be true and all the others are false, that is, in this array only one item can be true, with that I can show my dropdown item or even even apply a css effect to my active item, but for some reason my state never changes to true when clicked:

code:

```
const MenuItem = ({ tag, visibleMenu }) => {
  const { name, link, dropdownItems } = tag;
  return (
    <NavLi>
      <a>{name}</a>
      {visibleMenu[name] && dropdownItems ? (
        <DropDown>
          {dropdownItems.map(item => (
            <li>
              <a href={item.link}>{item.name}</a>
            </li>
          ))}
        </DropDown>
      ) : (
        ""
      )}
    </NavLi>
  );
};

const MenuBar = props => {
  const MenuTags = [
    {
      name: "home",
      link: "/",
      dropdownItems: [
        { name: "one", link: "/aa" },
        { name: "two", link: "/b/" }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "about",
      link: "../abovisibleMenuut",
      dropdownItems: [
        { name: "one", link: "/aa" },
        { name: "two", link: "/b/" }
      ]
    },
    { name: "not dropdown", link: "../dashboard" },
    { name: "not dropdown", link: "../dashboard/about" }
  ];
  const [visibleMenu, setVisibleMenu] = useState(
      MenuTags.reduce((r, e) => ((r[e.name] = false), r), {})
    ),
    onUpdateVisibility = item => {
      const visibleMenuCopy = { ...visibleMenu };
      Object.keys(visibleMenuCopy).forEach(
        key => (visibleMenuCopy[key] = key === item)
      );
      setVisibleMenu(visibleMenuCopy);
    };
  console.log(visibleMenu);
  return (
    <NavUl isOpen={props.isOpen}>
      {MenuTags.map(item => (
        <MenuItem
          tag={item}
          visibleMenu={visibleMenu}
          onClick={() => onUpdateVisibility(item)}
        />
      ))}
      <li>
        <FontAwesomeIcon
          onClick={() => props.setOpenBox(!props.isOpen)}
          className="searchIcon"
          rotation={90}
          icon={faSearch}
          size="1x"
          fixedWidth
          color="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);"
        />
      </li>
    </NavUl>
  );
};
```

example:

> https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-sammet-9qim9

I believe my problem is in my state:

```
  const [visibleMenu, setVisibleMenu] = useState(
      MenuTags.reduce((r, e) => ((r[e.name] = false), r), {}),
    ),
    onUpdateVisibility = item => {
      const visibleMenuCopy = { ...visibleMenu };
      Object.keys(visibleMenuCopy).forEach(
        key => (visibleMenuCopy[key] = key === item),
      );
      setVisibleMenu(visibleMenuCopy);
    };
      {MenuTags.map(item => (
        <MenuItem
          tag={item}
          visibleMenu={visibleMenu}
          onClick={() => onUpdateVisibility(item)}
        />
      ))}
```

But it was the only way I found to make only one state true at a time when it is clicked

Comment: Is the main point to be able determine (in state) which link object is active / which dropdown menu is open?

Comment: Yes the main point is to use the state to open the dropdown menu and also determine which menu item is currently active (ie which page is open for me to add a css effect to the item)

so only one item in that array can be true the rest false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the event handler was on a component that didn't return any concrete HTML elements.  `MenuTag` returns `NavLI`, which is a styled component, which returns an li.  I'm no master of styles components, but I think in general, event handlers need to be attached to DOM elements, not abstract React components.

Also, I think you can simplify this dramatically.  What about this:

```js
const [visible, setVisible] = useState('none'),

      {MenuTags.map( (item, index) => (
        <MenuItem
          key={index}
          tag={item}
          visibleMenu={visible === index ? true : false}
          onClick={() => setVisible(index)}
        />
      ))}
```

So what this does is say that within this component, we keep track of which item is visible with the `visible` state variable, which will be the index of the visible item.  The `onClick` handler changes this value to the index of the clicked item.  Then your prop `visibleMenu` will check this condition, making sure the index of that `MenuTag` is the same as the one in state.

### Edit

I changed a few things.  Instead of controlling the state from within MenuItem, we just pass a few props to MenuItem, and control them inside of MenuItem's subcomponent, NavLI, which accepts event handlers

```js
const MenuBar = props => {

  const [visible, setVisible] = useState('none')

  console.log(visible);
  return (
    <NavUl isOpen={props.isOpen}>
      {MenuTags.map( (item, index) => (
        <MenuItem
          key={index}
          index={index}
          tag={item}
          setVisible={setVisible}
          visibleMenu={visible === index ? true : false}
        />
      ))}

// Inside NavLI

const MenuItem = ({ tag, visibleMenu, setVisible, index }) => {
  ...
  return (
    <NavLi onMouseEnter={ () => { console.log(index); setVisible(index) }} 
      onMouseLeave={() => { setVisible('none')}} >
  ...
```

I changed the handlers to `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave`.  `onClick` will work, but you'd need a global event handler for the page to `setVisible` back to 'none', so that when you click anywhere else on the page, the tabs close.  There's more nuance there than that, but my example should work.

### [Working Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/drop-down-menu-i0j5f)

Comment: this part of resuming setVisible to none I was confused I can't imagine how I could do this

Comment: can helpme please?

Comment: I edited my answer and made you a working codesandbox.  If you don't mind using a ready-out-of-the-box solution for a navbar like what you're trying to create, I'd check out [react-bootstrap's navbar](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/), which has the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: thanks a lot bro I managed to do something to use the handle click

Thanks a lot for the help